# what are the benefits of always running from live cd for data protection?

Tags: encryption, disk, livecd, persistence

Wanted to create a list of all the benefits of always running from a live CD (with or without persistence/as long as personal data is saved on encrypted drive locally)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a live ISO without persistence means the main filesystem is read-only, so nothing can be changed or "broken" permanently. It also means all changes (new files & data) are in ram and lost on reboot/shutdown.

Saving your personal data manually could lead to better backup habits...

If you have enough ram to use the `toram` option, all file reads & writes will be at ram speeds, maybe 2GB-5GB per second, much faster than a regular cd/dvd/hard drive or ssd.

---

The "best encryption" part of the question really is too broad, but just use the defaults the big distros use: GPG, LUKS, eCryptfs

Comment: Can the iso access all filesystems it connects to, eg; running ubuntu live on ntfs file system but connecting to and saving to encrypted fat32 or ext4? Benefits and limitations list somewhere of live OSs?

Comment: They can generally access anything a regular system can. What do you mean *"running ubuntu live **on ntfs file system**"*? A live filesystem is in ram, and reading static files from it's own ISO. Sometimes a live DVD or USB uses fat, sometimes ext, ntfs might be supported by some, but since it doesn't generally write there it doesn't generally matter, and if it's running `toram` then you can remove the DVD/USB completely

Comment: The biggest benefit *and* limitation is that **all changes are lost, unless saved**. You might want to try a distribution that can easily create a new ISO or "update" (save changes to) a live USB like MX-Linux (running live you can install updates & make config changes then create a new ISO or save back to the USB from the live system. I'm pretty sure AntiX and Puppy Linux have similar features.

Comment: So when running live the os can save files and changes to a local drive and then when you reconnect its all there?

Comment: That's basically how persistence works, usually saving changes to the live USB, some distros can run "live" from a hard drive (some easier than others). Without persistence only mounted physical partitions (a hard or USB drive) have changes saved. Being familiar with `mount` (`lsblk`'s nice too, or `gnome-disk-utility`) and general linux filesystems is good, to check what's mounted where, since all the other system files are in `/` which is ram

Comment: Thank you for follow up. I think I understand now. As long as you run an operating system live from any media its just like having a os on your hd but only the data outside of that drive will be saved (if any) unless a persistence partition is added for that os on the drive from which it is running. Doesn't matter which filesystem as long as the os can recognize it. I will definitely be looking into the filesystem more. Thank you again.

Comment: That's about it. Running live (no persistence) is great for learning too, accidentally erasing important files - home or all of `/` - (things not on a mounted drive) is only a problem until you reboot. Or changing to "bad" sources and creating broken packages (lots of people break their systems and look for help fixing broken packages). I've run linux live for years, and only save a few config files from home, like browser profiles. "Installing" a whole new OS/version means d/l a new ISO, boot & copy a few config files, then create my custom ISO (MX's snapshot or remastercc). You're welcome :)